# AttributeError: module 'azure.functions' has no attribute 'SqlRowList'

Tags: python, azure-functions

Despite having set PYTHON_ISOLATE_WORKER_DEPENDENCIES to 1 in the app config
[config app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz4mE.png)

I have the following issue when accessing api from my static web app (issue i don't have when i'm debugging locally so i guess it's a matter of libs and python versioning).
I'm debugging with python 3.9. and i'm using : azure-functions==1.11.3b1

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.GetUserConfig Result: Failure
Exception: AttributeError: module 'azure.functions' has no attribute 'SqlRowList'
Stack:   File "/azure-functions- 
host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 314, in 
_handle__function_load_request
func = loader.load_function(
File "/azure-functions- 
host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in 
call
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/azure-functions- 
host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 85, in 
load_function
mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/site/wwwroot/GetUserConfig/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, ressources: func.SqlRowList) -> func.HttpResponse:
```

Can you please help on that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome the issue by rolling back the version to azure-functions==1.11.0 and not defining the SqlRowList type in the main function, which results in it being passed in as a string and then you can convert it as required:

`def main(req: func.HttpRequest, ressources) -> func.HttpResponse:`